# 2020 Census Data

Tags: geospatial, census

I have data from when the 2020 census from when it was first published, but it's missing certain fields (median household income, no vehicle households, etc.), I'm assuming those were added in subsequent years, and want to find the most up to date dataset. I'm not sure where to download this from.

Do you know where I could obtain this?

Comment: Hi. I assume you're talking about the US census, but if not you should specify which country you're interested in.

Comment: Ah, right. I am. I should have stated that.

Answer (score 3):

The 2020 Decennial Census does not collect that kind of information. You can see what kind of questions were asked of households in [this sample questionnaire](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial/2020/technical-documentation/questionnaires-and-instructions/questionnaires/2020-informational-questionnaire-english_DI-Q1.pdf).

If you want to check out a survey that does ask [those questions](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/methodology/questionnaires/2020/quest20.pdf), check the American Community Survey (ACS). I would also recommend using https://data.census.gov/ to retrieve the info just for quick checks.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check the ACS, I just assumed, incorrectly, that it would be included with the Census data.